# How to create my user name and password

Tags: password

I just bought my new HP laptop and the OS is Ubuntu. It never asked for my password when I first used it and I never made one. Every time I try to add or download stuff it always asks for my password that I never made.
Please help me.

Comment: That's definitely not normal. On the Desktop, do you see an icon that says "Prepare for shipping to end user"?

Comment: Did you buy it off the display?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

From this source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/

You’ll want to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD, choosing **“Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer”** from the boot menu.
Once the system boots, open up a new Terminal window from **Applications \ Accessories** and then type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command is used to tell what device name the hard drive is using, which in most cases should be `/dev/sda1`, but could be different on your system.

Now you’ll need to create a directory to mount the hard drive on. Since we’re actually booting off the live cd, the directory doesn’t really get created anywhere.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda
```

The next command will mount the hard drive in the /media/sda1 folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

Now it’s time for the command that actually does the magic: `chroot`. This command is used to open up a shell with a different root directory than the current shell is using, and we’ll pass in the folder where we mounted the hard drive.

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

Now you should be able to use the passwd command to change your user account’s password, and it will be applied to the hard drive since we are using chroot.

```
passwd geek
```

*Note that you’ll have to type your username after the passwd command in order to change the right password.*

Now you should be able to reboot your system and log yourself in with your new password.

It's worked for me.

Comment: Could you please add in your answer the relevant portion of your link as suggested by [AskUbuntu help](http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Is there's still something wrong?

Comment: good job => so +1

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening a terminal window by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
passwd
```

And for root:

```
sudo passwd
```

If there was no password set, you can enter a new one.

But I think it is not possible to setup Ubuntu without a password, maybe autologin is enabled, or factory setup was not finished successfully.

Comment: Thanks for editing Pandaya, I am relatively new to askubuntu, even though beeing signed for up some time now.